# What does "ci_bound" in SequentialFeatureSelector mean?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, confidence-interval

I was following one of the tutorials online regarding stepwise regressions using the `boston` dataset. There is nothing wrong with the code but I just want to understand what I'm seeing. So I have ran the forward selection below:

```
sfs = SFS(LinearRegression(), 
          k_features=(3,11), 
          forward=True, 
          floating=False,
          scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
          cv=4)
sfs.fit(X, y)
```

After that, I am visualising the data in DataFrame as seen below:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sfs.get_metric_dict()).T
```

which gives me:
[image: visualising data in DataFrame]

What does the values in column `ci_bound` mean?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using mlxtend's [`SequentialFeatureSelector`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector/). What algorithms of this family do is add or remove features and analyse the impact they have on the algorithms metrics. As mentioned in the docs, the `ci_bound` gives you the `confidence interval around the computed cross-validation scores`. By default, a `95%` confidence interval is used, but you can set it to another value using `confidence_interval`.

Confidence intervals are presumably obtained by repeating the cross validation `K` times ([K-Fold cross validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/)). So what you're seeing in the resulting dataframe, are the scores derived from estimating with a given subset of features, and the confidence interval associated to those scores.

Comment: You're right. I have read the docs, but still not quite sure what the values in the `ci_bound` column means. Example, for row 1, the ci_bound value is 31.189. What does 31.189 mean in this context? Appreciate if there is a layman explanation for this.

Comment: it is the confidence interval of the average score. It is a measure of uncertainty of the scores you see. The lower, the more you can "trust" those scores @ZhengYang

Comment: I see, thanks. With a CI of the average score of > 25, I assume that means that these scores are "not trustworthy"

Comment: Yes. That will probably only occur for small amounts of features @ZhengYang